# what is the Key Value pair to define Replication Factor in the json object

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-http

-d '{"DatabaseName": "DB_Name", "ReplicationFactor": "3"}'

The replication factor key value pair seems to be wrong and CURL command ignores this value while creating a database and sets the replication factor to 1.

Please tell me know the correct Key value name to define replication factor.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a cluster configured ? In order to create a database with a replication factor > 1 you should have that number of nodes up and running.

Comment: yes i have a cluster configured.  By the way i fixed this problem.   curl.exe -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"DatabaseName\": \"DB_Kanna2\"}' --cert "LocalMachine\My\xxx" --key "D:\RavenDB\certificates\xxx.key" https://xxx:000/admin/databases?replicationFactor=3.  We need to mention the replication factor at the end of the server url